# Differentiate receive message and sent message in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sms

i am developing an SMS app. i want to differentiate the sent message and received message for a particular number. for example you can see in SMS app that sent message displayed in right side and received message displayed in left side.

How to do this layout any can help?

Comment: For SMS for sure you are using some POJO class. In that pojo class you need to declare one variable naming isMine and set it true/false on base you send message or receiver message respectively.

Comment: what do you want logic or code..and for what design or functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if your concern is about the layout or the Sms's .
Anyway, make sure your POJO class retains the timestamp of received/sent message so to be able to order your elements on the layout..

For the layouting i suggest you to try to figure out by drawing (literally draw on a sheet or some editor) a mockup for the screen considering orientation and sizes.
Probably you will use a ListView to render your sms, but first you need to make a picture in your mind of what and how you need to display the messages.